# pthread_create changes values of an array

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a problem with pthread_create. In this test, I create an array of integers, and then try to use them as parameters for a function that must be executed into a thread.

This is where I create the indexes:

```
int *indexes = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*threadNumber);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++){
    indexes[i] = i;
}
```

And this is where I create threads:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++){
    printf("%i %i    ", i, indexes[i]);
}
for (i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++){
    printf("%i %i    ", i, indexes[i]);
    pthread_create(sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i, NULL, sonSimulation, (void *) &indexes[i]);
}
```

The first printf prints the following:

```
0 0   1 1   2 2   3 3   4 4
```

The second one, which is supposed to print the same output, prints this:

```
0 0   1 1   2 2   3 3   4 23154684
```

The last number changes each time I executes the code.
I'm not able to fix this. Any suggestion?

(sonSimulation just prints the parameter)

Comment: What is `sons`? How is it declared? Why don't you use plain array indexing for it? Also, you're threads doesn't overwrite the pointer they get?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try `sons[i]` or `sons + i` instead of `sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i`. Also, please post the `sonSimulation` function.

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: This is where i declare sons     pthread_t *sons = (pthread_t * ) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threadNumber);

Comment: Please provide the definition of sonSimulation function or if possible the complete program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
pthread_create(sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i, NULL, sonSimulation, (void *) &indexes[i]);
```

You allocate `sons` using

```
pthread_t *sons = (pthread_t * ) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threadNumber);
```

So, `sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i` in the `pthread_create` is wrong. When you use `sons+i`, it automatically moves the `sons` pointer `sizeof(pthread_t)` bytes forward because of pointer arithmetic. Using `sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i` moves the pointer into invalid memory locations invoking Undefined Behavior.

To fix the problem, use

```
pthread_create(sons + i, NULL, sonSimulation, (void *) &indexes[i]);
```

or

```
pthread_create(&sons[i], NULL, sonSimulation, (void *) &indexes[i]);
```

instead of

```
pthread_create(sons + sizeof(pthread_t)*i, NULL, sonSimulation, (void *) &indexes[i]);
```

---

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you [need not cast the result of `malloc`(and family)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) in C.
The `void*` cast in the last argument of is not needed either as [@JoachimPileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975104/pthread-create-changes-values-of-an-array/30975626?noredirect=1#comment49982693_30975626).

Comment: That cast in `pthread_create` for the thread function argument is not needed either.

Comment: I thought that `void*` can be converted to any other type without a cast, but the opposite needs a cast. So `void*` can be converted to and from without a cast?

Comment: @CoolGuy: "*So `void*` can be converted to and from without a cast?*" to/from any other pointer type, yes.